# CruiseControl & Git not checking the branch out

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I am developing a build automation to b used with CruiseControl.NET.
In my ccnet.config file, I have the following sourcecontrol tag:

```
<sourcecontrol type="git">
      <repository>sourceControlAddress</repository>
      <branch>release-0.9.19</branch>
      <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
      <fetchSubmodules>true</fetchSubmodules>
      <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe</executable>
      <tagOnSuccess>false</tagOnSuccess>
      <commitBuildModifications>false</commitBuildModifications>
      <commitUntrackedFiles>false</commitUntrackedFiles>
      <tagCommitMessage>Build {0}</tagCommitMessage>
      <tagNameFormat>Build-{0}</tagNameFormat>
      <committerName>Build</committerName>
      <committerEMail>build@build.com</committerEMail>
      <workingDirectory>d:\GIT\Sources\WEB</workingDirectory>
      <timeout>60000</timeout>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

The only problem I currently have is that it "erases" any checkout information I had.
For instance: if I open the solution in git extensions and check a branch out then run the automated build, if I open git extensions again, I will have a "no branch" instead of my branch I selected.
This causes issues, specially when I try to check things in in my build script, because I get a message saying: "Not currently on any branch."

How do I set the branch to be used and checked out?
(The branch property hsa the correct name of the branch and the autoGetSource is set to true)

Thanks!

EDIT: I ran CC.net in the console and I got his info:

> [Git] Calling git checkout -q -f origin/release-0.9.19

The checkout is correctly being called. But it, for some reason is being "cleared" when it runs. 
Maybe because of

> [Git] Calling git clean -d -f -x

?

Answer (score 1):

The git source control provider was never be designed wo work together with user "users" then itsself. So it only support to checkout a remote branch without creating a local tracking branch to avoid merge conflicts.

So why do you work in the same working directory as CCNet?

Comment: I am just checking with the extesions. I would like to increase the build version and, for that, I would have to check in the assembly info and, for that, I would have to have the branch checked out.

Comment: I have the same problem. My build is using labeller in order to increase build number and it should commit changes to GIT to have the latest build number there.